# JavaScript - Best way to always access a specific Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, scope, this

If I create an Object as follows:

```
window.Something = {
    X: function() {
        // statements...
    }
};
```

What is the best way to access this object without using `this`?

**Example:**

If I call the `X` property by using:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", window.Something.X);
```

In this case using `this` will access window and not `Something`.
I thought at this method but I think it is a bad practice.

```
window.Something = {
    X: function() {
        var This = window.Something;

        // statements...
    }
};
```

There is an implicit way to always access the `real` object that created the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody has pointed out ***why*** this is occurring.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> When attaching a handler function to an element using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), the value of `this` inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

In other words, `this` refers to the `window` object because the event listener is attached to the `window` object. For instance, if you attached the event listener to an `input` element, `this.name` would refer to the `name` attribute of the `input` element that the event was attached to.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kqtw894/)

```js
window.Something = {
  name: 'Some name',
  X: function() {
    console.log(this.name); // 'test'
  }
};

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('input', Something.X);
```

```html
<input id="target" name="test" />
```

---

As others have pointed out, you can either change the value of `this` by using the [`bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmdzru5y/)

```js
window.Something = {
    name: 'Some name',
    X: function () {
        console.log(this.name); // 'Some name'
    }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Something.X.bind(Something));
```

Alternatively, you could also just execute the `X` method inside of an anonymous function. This will prevent the `addEventListener()` method from modifying the value of `this`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gycnenjh/)

```js
window.Something = {
    name: 'Some name',
    X: function () {
        console.log(this.name); // 'Some name'
    }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    Something.X();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then you probably want to use `bind`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

To do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Something.X.bind(Something));
```

This will ensure that within the call to `Something.X`, `this` points to `Something`.

More useful info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I think that there is no no need for bind, this will be set to "Something" anyway, also no need for window, if created in the global context it doesn't matter.

Comment: @vtz No, `bind()` or something similar is needed. In the context of an event handler, `this` will *not* be the object containing `X`, it will be the object on which the event was fired (`window`, in this case).

Comment: I do not agree, you can check my answer below, ofcourse if i am mistaken i will gladly remove my answer @PaulRoub

Comment: You added a wrapper function. That would be the "something similar" I mentioned. `bind()` eliminates the need for that here.

Comment: I stand corrected, i will change my answer and will remove bind(), thanks @PaulRoub

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to call the handler with the appropriate `this`:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", window.Something.X.bind(window.Something));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to refer window (windows is always the object when you are declaring variables in the global scope), also you can use bind() or wrapper function. this will refer to the first object in scope. Try the below code

```
Something = {
    X: function()
    {
        // statements...
        console.log(this);

    }
};
window.addEventListener('click',function(){Something.X()});
```